# Meteor, JavaScript & jQuery - .fadeIn function refusing to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

jQuery doesn't seem to be working at all.
I've got this enclosed in my header block:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've got a div: < div id="msg">something random

A button:

```
<input type="button" class="code btn span4" id="lumb" value="Sell Lumber" />
```

And the code to activate the fade:

```
Template.hello.events({
'click input.code': function () {
 Meteor.call('sell');
 Template.hello.greeting = "text";
 return greeting;
$('#msg').fadeOut('slow');
}
});
```

Does anyone know why the fade isn't working?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "Template.hello.*" which I'm assuming must be meteor code, but you have "return greeting;" prior to the fadeOut call.  Is that line not getting hit?

Comment: It's code to do with Meteor, yes. But when I return the greeting, it's updating the div which I want to fade out. If I do what you suggested, it's going to fade out before anything has been returned.

Comment: It should be instantaneous... and the fade is set to 'slow' so you will see the text first.

Comment: Eh, I tried it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Does the message even display? "greeting" doesn't seem to be defined so I'm wondering if you need to even return it?  You are setting it on Template.hello.greeting Is that what you need to return instead?  Try commenting out the return first.

Comment: `Template.hello.greeting = "text";` is where it's defined.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46967/discussion-between-iii-and-user3102516)

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're returning your callback function before calling jQuery. Change your function to:

```
Template.hello.events({
    'click input.code': function () {
        Meteor.call('sell');
        Template.hello.greeting = "text";
        $('#msg').fadeOut('slow');
        return greeting;
    }
});
```

Comment: The return doesn't matter, in fact, it should return the text first. The {greeting} is the text displayed inside the div which I want to fade out. So this is actually incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like your link to jQuery is complete. You're missing "http:" ?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Should be:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `//` just means autoresolves between `http` and `https`. This is a common practice

Answer (score 0):

[See this link for information on "return"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

> Example: Interrupt a function
>
> A function immediately stops at the point where return is called.

You have a return before the .fadeOut call in your function.  Place your return after all functionality in the function:

```
$('#msg').fadeOut('slow');
return greeting;
```

As another answer indicates you should also make sure jQuery is being referenced properly.  Use http:// instead of just // in the src attribute.

Check that jQuery is working on the page first using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("jQuery works");
        //or if console.log doesn't work for you
        //alert("jQuery works");
});
```

Are you sure the function that is setting the greeting is getting hit?  Use `console.log` and/or alerts to determine that the function is getting hit.  Perhaps you don't need a return at all in that function, but the variable `greeting` doesn't appear to be defined.  You are returning `greeting` and not `Template.hello.greeting`.

You state `.fadeIn` in the title, but have `.fadeOut` in your code.  What are you trying to do?  Show or hide the #msg element?